# pg_upgradecluster fails with 'tablespace directory "" does not exist' error

Tags: postgresql, tablespaces

I'm trying to upgrade a Postgres cluster from PG 12 to PG 15 using this command :

```
sudo pg_upgradecluster 12 main --method=link
```

My cluster uses some tablespaces:

```
postgres=# SELECT oid, spcname, pg_tablespace_location(oid) FROM pg_tablespace;
    oid     |      spcname       |      pg_tablespace_location      
------------+--------------------+----------------------------------
       1664 | pg_global          | 
       1663 | default_old        | 
 1905123481 | ts1                | /mnt/postgres/ts1
 1905522771 | ts2                | /mnt/postgres/ts2
 1905595436 | ts3                | /mnt/postgres/ts3
```

When I run the pg_upgradecluster script, it fails immediately with this error :

```
tablespace directory "" does not exist
```

All the tablespaces are located on different disks

I've already upgraded another cluster which doesn't have tablespaces from PG 12 to PG 15 without any errors.

I don't understand what to do now :(

does anyone faced this issue before and knows how to fix it ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `ALTER TABLESPACE default_old RENAME TO pg_default;`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe
thx for your feedback, unfortunately, the "pg_" prefix is reserved for postgres system stuff... I'm not allowed to change it to this value.

Comment: You have to set `allow_system_table_mods = on` for that to succeed. But why on earth did you break your database by renaming a system tablespace in the first place?

Comment: don't ask :D
I'm here to fix things that others have broken....
but when things go south, it becomes my problem, obviously :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as expected, the fact that the "pg_default" namespace has been renamed is the reason why the pg_upgradecluster script fails right away.

to fix this issue, as I stayed before, a simple rename doesn't work.
I've had to be a bit more sneaky :

```sql
update pg_tablespace set spcname = 'pg_default' where spcname = 'default_old';
```

et voilà ! :)